# W32 textbox automatic newline

Tags: c, windows, winapi

So I have a textbox and I want to make it go to a new line when it reaches the border. Also, I am new to this w32 API. Here is my code:

```
hEdit=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
                     WS_BORDER, 10,
                     10, 160, 420, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                     NULL);
HGDIOBJ hfDefault=GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault,
            MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));
SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETTEXT, NULL,
            (LPARAM)"Insert text here...");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the ES_MULTILINE style when creating the control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464(v=vs.85).aspx